# Literally Canvas - I can not find any tools on my page?

Tags: html, canvas, drag-and-drop, drawing

### My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Literally Canvas</title>
    <link href="css/literallycanvas.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="react-with-addons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/literallycanvas-core.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/literallycanvas.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="literally"></div>
    <form class="controls export">
        <input type="submit" data-action="export-as-png" value="Export as PNG">
    </form>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){  
              //initial without jQuery
              var lc = LC.init(
                      document.getElementsByClassName('literally')[0],{
                          imageURLPrefix:'img',
                          primaryColor:'#fff',
                          backgroundColor:'#ddd',
                          toolbarPosition:'top',
                          tools:
                                  [
                                      LC.tools.Pencil,
                                      LC.tools.Eraser,
                                      LC.tools.Line,
                                      LC.tools.Rectangle,
                                      LC.tools.Text,
                                      LC.tools.Polygon
                                  ]
                      });
            //export as png
              $('.controls.export [data-action=export-as-png]').click(function(e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  window.open(lc.getImage().toDataURL());
              });             
          });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have download **literallycanvas-0.4.11** and added the files under `css/` and `img/` to my project, as well as the appropriate file from `js/`.
I can see the initial is worked because I can see the primaryColor was changed but I can't find my tools.
I followed the [literally canvas](http://literallycanvas.com/api/index.html/%22literally%20canvas%22) however it still something wrong.
Anybody can help me??

Comment: Hi, Literally Canvas maintainer here. You should include either literallycanvas.js *or* literallycanvas-core.js, not both. Try removing the "core" version and try again.

Comment: In case if only literallycanvas-core.js is included then the toolbar is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `imageURLPrefix` option and it worked for me. Just write path to your `img` folder there.

```
var lc = LC.init(
    document.getElementsByClassName('my-drawing')[0],
    {
       imageURLPrefix: 'path/to/your/img',
       .....     
       ..... 
    });
```